# Esri Geotrigger tutorial

Tags: arcgis-android, esri-geotrigger-service

I completed the "Configuring Push Notification" part of the Esri geotrigger for Android. However, I keep getting the "unable to load device" error. What could be the reasons for getting this error?

The error appears after running this method:

```
GeotriggerService.init(context, CLIENT_ID, GCM_SENDER_ID,
                GeotriggerService.TRACKING_PROFILE_ADAPTIVE);

    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("text", "Push notifications are working!");
        params.put("url", "http://developers.arcgis.com");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating device/notify params", e);
    }

    GeotriggerApiClient.runRequest(context, "device/notify", params, new GeotriggerApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {
            Log.i(TAG, "device/notify success: " + json);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "device/notify failure", error);
        }
    });
```

And my manifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<permission
    android:name="com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<permission android:name="com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

"

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Fashionstreet" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".ShopListActivity" />

    <service
        android:name="com.esri.android.geotrigger.GeotriggerService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.esri.android.geotrigger.MessageReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>

            <category android:name="com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <data android:path="com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet"
                android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BlogWebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShopListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".HelpActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FindShopActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyANuB4sP5a_NtDGWZ8dE3SYcJGN4IfmLj8" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ShopWebViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Testing"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_testing" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here's a copy of the main activity:

```
package com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.esri.android.geotrigger.GeotriggerApiClient;
import com.esri.android.geotrigger.GeotriggerApiListener;
import com.esri.android.geotrigger.GeotriggerService;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ShopListActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener  {
    protected Context context;
    protected String[] mShops;
    protected String[] mCategory_names;
    protected String[] mLocate_shops_names;
    protected String[] mWebsites;
    protected GridView mGridView;
    protected ListView mListView;
    protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    protected TextView emptyTextView;
    protected ShopLayoutAdapter adapter;
    protected ArrayList<String> shops_arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected String CLIENT_ID = "Q0bPdyhOItoWPBTw";
    protected final String GCM_SENDER_ID = "851435869460";
    protected final String TAG = ShopListActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    protected final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    protected static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    String SENDER_ID = "851435869460";
    static final String GCM_TAG = "GCM";

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    String regid;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_list);


        Intent i = getIntent();
        // mGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.shops_grid);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shoplistView1);

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

        Resources resource = getResources();
        mCategory_names = resource.getStringArray(R.array.category_names);
        mWebsites = resource.getStringArray(R.array.websites);
        mShops = resource.getStringArray(R.array.list_shops);
        for(int index = 0; index < mShops.length; index ++){
            Log.i("ShopListActivity", "Here!!! " + mShops[index]);
            shops_arrlist.add(mShops[index]);
        }
        mLocate_shops_names = resource
                .getStringArray(R.array.locate_shops_names);
        emptyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        //Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        //  GCM registration.
        /**
        if(checkPlayServices()){
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);


            if(regid.isEmpty()){
               registerInBackground  register = new registerInBackground();
                register.execute();
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.i(GCM_TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
         */
        GeotriggerService.init(context, CLIENT_ID, GCM_SENDER_ID,
                GeotriggerService.TRACKING_PROFILE_ADAPTIVE);

        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        try {
            params.put("text", "Push notifications are working!");
            params.put("url", "http://developers.arcgis.com");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating device/notify params", e);
        }

        GeotriggerApiClient.runRequest(context, "device/notify", params, new GeotriggerApiListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject json) {
                Log.i(TAG, "device/notify success: " + json);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "device/notify failure", error);
            }
        });

        handleIntent(i);
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    /*
    protected boolean checkPlayServices(){
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)){
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            }

            else{
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported");
                finish();
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    */

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    /*
    protected String getRegistrationId(Context context){
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if(registrationId.isEmpty()){
            Log.i(GCM_TAG, "Registration not found");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing registration ID is not guaranteed to work with
        // the new app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if(registeredVersion != currentVersion){
            Log.i(GCM_TAG, "App Version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
    */

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    /*
    protected SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the registration ID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(TAG,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
    */

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    /*
    protected static int getAppVersion(Context context){
        try{
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        }
        catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            //should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }
    */

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    /*
    protected class registerInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                    // is using accounts.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                    // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the registration ID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
    }
    */

    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    /*
    protected void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
    }
    */

    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param
     * @param
     */
    /*
    protected void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId){
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(GCM_TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }
    */



    private void handleIntent(Intent i) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(i.getAction())) {
            String query = i.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Log.i("Search Activated", "SEARCH!!!!!");
            //doMySearch(query);
            // use the query to search your data somehow
        }

        else {
            adapter = new ShopLayoutAdapter(this,shops_arrlist);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String category_name = mCategory_names[position];
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ShopListActivity.this,
                            MainListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("category_name", category_name);
                    intent.putExtra("real_shop_name",
                            mLocate_shops_names[position]);
                    intent.putExtra("toast_notification", mShops[position]);
                    intent.putExtra("shop_website", mWebsites[position]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /**
    private void doMySearch(String query) {
        String search_results = "";
        int num_results = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < mShops.length; i++){

            if (mShops[i].indexOf(query) > -1 && num_results == 0) 
            {
                search_results = mShops[i];
                num_results ++;
            } 
            else if (mShops[i].indexOf(query) > -1 && num_results > 0) 
            {
                search_results = search_results + "|" + mShops[i];
                num_results++;
            }

        }
        if(search_results.length() > 0){
            ArrayList<String> results_arr = search_results.split("|");
            adapter = new ShopLayoutAdapter(this, results_arr);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String category_name = mCategory_names[position];
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ShopListActivity.this,
                            MainListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("category_name", category_name);
                    intent.putExtra("real_shop_name",
                            mLocate_shops_names[position]);
                    intent.putExtra("toast_notification", mShops[position]);
                    intent.putExtra("shop_website", mWebsites[position]);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        else
            mListView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
    }

    */

    /*
    @Override
    protected void onGridItemClick(GridView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onGridItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String category_name = mCategory_names[position];
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("category_name", category_name);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.shop_list, menu);

        //MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        //SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_help){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_contact_us){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(id == R.id.action_search){
            onSearchRequested();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
        Log.i("QueryChange", "Change!!!!" + arg0);
        adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }
    */
}
```

Here is the error log generated:

```
05-14 15:45:28.666    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Unable to load Device. Device not saved.
05-14 15:45:39.698    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Unable to load Device. Device not saved.
05-14 15:45:39.698    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Unable to load device! Device is null.
05-14 15:45:39.698    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Cannot perform Geotrigger API request. Device is not registered or is invalid.
05-14 15:45:39.746    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/ShopListActivity﹕ device/notify failure
    java.lang.Exception: Cannot perform Geotrigger API request. Device is not registered or is invalid.
            at com.esri.android.geotrigger.GeotriggerApiClient.runRequest(GeotriggerApiClient.java:70)
            at com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet.ShopListActivity.onCreate(ShopListActivity.java:119)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 15:45:43.346    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Unable to load Device. Device not saved.
05-14 15:45:51.806    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
05-14 15:45:51.818    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
05-14 15:45:54.330    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
05-14 15:45:54.762    1427-1427/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
05-14 15:46:08.078    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ [ktvw0] Request failed!
05-14 15:46:08.098    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Failed to register device!
05-14 15:46:08.642    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ [984y4] Request failed!
05-14 15:46:08.798    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Failed to register device!
05-14 15:46:30.394    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ [6nyeo] Request failed!
05-14 15:46:30.438    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Failed to register device!
05-14 15:46:54.082    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ [egk92] Request failed!
05-14 15:46:54.086    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Failed to register device!
05-14 15:47:21.686    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ [9jh2d] Request failed!
05-14 15:47:21.690    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Failed to register device!
05-14 15:47:57.486    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ [qj6g0] Request failed!
05-14 15:47:57.490    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Failed to register device!
05-14 15:48:49.778    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ [z3vmc] Request failed!
05-14 15:48:49.982    1427-1455/com.elikemkuivi.fashionstreet E/GeotriggerSDK_v1.1.0﹕ Failed to register device!
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with more information? What steps are you taking before you get the error?

Comment: i added my manifest file, and the code block where the error occurs, and a copy of the mainactivity where the method is being called. The error occurs after i have added permissions to the manifest file, registered for GCM on the Google API console, and decide to test for push notifications

Comment: I found the answer. Just set the application access to public and it should work.